# How to fix "addChild(locked_jwb);" only show on frame 3

Tags: actionscript-3

```
var locked_jwb:MovieClip=new sudah_jawab;

a_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ev1a);

function ev1a(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    score_ev = score_ev +1;
    gotoAndStop(4);
    addChild(locked_jwb);
    locked_jwb.x=523.15;
    locked_jwb.y=-94.05;
}
```

my problem

```
addChild(locked_jwb);
```

I want addchild ... only on frame number (4)

Comment: Hi Johnsen, your questions is pretty unclear, it's hard to tell what your problem is. Are you getting any errors? What do you expect to happen? Please read the [article on how to ask a good SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

```
function ev1a(event:MouseEvent):void
{
        score_ev = score_ev +1;
        addChild(locked_jwb);
        locked_jwb.x=523.15;
        locked_jwb.y=-94.05;

        gotoAndStop(4); //move this down here

}
```

There are many problem with this style of writing but I will cut the chase. You need to set the coordinates before moving to frame 4.

Comment: I don't think that makes any difference. Please explain why do you think there would be any.

Comment: assuming this is written on frame 3, on frame 4 there might not be a locked_jwb reference.

Comment: The **locked_jwb** object is an explicitly declared variable, not an auto-declared timeline instance. It should be available on absolutely any frame. Also it should not be **null** at any moment after the frame with **new sudah_jawab** instruction.